# Foreign key null when persisting one to many unidirectional relationship

Tags: hibernate, junit

### Context

I have 2 entities, mapped like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
private String mail;

@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE} fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Food> foods;
```

and Food:

```
@Entity
public class Food{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

My Test:

```
@Test   
public void testPersistUserWithFood() throws Exception{
  //I create and persist the user
  User user = new User ("@someone");
  Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
  sess.save(user);
  tx.commit();
  sess.close();      

  //Now I create de food and set the relation in object schema
  Food foo = new Food();
  user.getFoods.add(foo);

  //I persist the food in the same way than user, with session, transaction and so on.

  //Then I retrieve the user from DB
  sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  User userRetrieved =(User) sess.createCriteria(User.class)
                 .add(Restrictions.idEq("@someone")).uniqueResult();
  sess.close();

  //Finally assert
  assertEquals(user.getFoods(), userRetrieved.getFoods());

}
```

## The problem

The test fails, because the call: userRetrieved.getFoods() return a null list.
When I have debuged, I saw the id_User foreing column in table Food always null. 
If the relationship is oneToMany bidirectional the column id_User is not null, because I add user property in Food class.

Thanks for your help!

Note: I am using hibernate 4.3.8, jUnit 4 and java 8

Answer (score 0):

```
userRetrieved.getFoods() return a null list.
```

This means that user is not updated when you're adding food.

```
...
...

  //Now I create de food and set the relation in object schema

  //I persist the food in the same way than user, with session, transaction and so on.
  Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();

  Food foo = new Food();
  user.getFoods.add(foo);

  sess.update(user);    //are you updating User as well like this?
  sess.save(foo);
  tx.commit();
  sess.close();
...
...
```

*P.S. If it doesn't work, then kindly post your complete code that shows how you're persisting all entities.*

Answer (score 0):

You have the `id_User` column `null` because of `id` equals `null` in the new `Food` object here

```
Food foo = new Food();
user.getFoods().add(foo);
```

To fix this issue you need to save a new `Foo` object to Hibernate assign an `id` for it. And after that add saved `Foo` to the `foods` collection. Or you can use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to Hibernate save new child objects with a parent

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Food> foods;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, I solved my problem, this is the code:

### One entity

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
private String mail;

@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE} fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="id_User")
private Set<Food> foods;
```

### Many entity

```
@Entity
public class Food{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

### Test

```
 @Test   
 public void testPersistUserWithFood() throws Exception{

  //I create and persist the user
  User user = new User ("@someone");
  Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
  sess.save(user);
  tx.commit();
  sess.close();      

  //Now I create de food and set the relation in object schema
  Food foo = new Food();
  user.getFoods.add(foo);

  //I persist the food in the same way than user, with session, transaction and so on.

  //Hibernate don´t know that the user contains the food when persist the
  // food, because the relationship is unidirectional, therefore:
  sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  tx = sess.beginTransaction();
  sess.update(user);
  tx.commit();
  sess.close();  

  //Then I retrieve the user from DB
  sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  User userRetrieved =(User) sess.createCriteria(User.class)
             .add(Restrictions.idEq("@someone")).uniqueResult();
  sess.close();


  //Finally assert
  assertEquals(user.getFoods(), userRetrieved.getFoods());

}
```

Summary:

1. Save user
2. Save food
3. Update user

Thanks a lot!.